# Interpreting genealogical dates

Tags: united-states, date, citation

Example:
[image: Mary's baptism]

So when was Mary actually baptized?   1744 or 1745 ?

Is there something I need to understand about **why** it would have been reported with two different dates?

Comment: Take a look at these Qs and let us know if the information there isn't enough to answer your question.  https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-date